# Review queue red dot appears when all queues available are empty

Tags: support, review-queues, top-bar, notifications

I often get the red dot notification on the review queues button in the top right of the top bar. Sometimes when I click on the button, all of the review queues are empty. I understand that they just have been reviewed before I have opened review page.

Why does the red dot appear when there are no review queues with enough review tasks available to warrant the notification?